# Using Dynamic Action for multiple checkboxes

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle Apex, I am currently creating a form. Within the form there is a checkbox item that shows a LOV. One of the options is labeled 'others'. The goal is to have a text box appear when 'others' is checked. I am unsure on which dynamic action to use for this situation. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Create text field lets say `P1_text`then create a dynamic action with the following options:

1. Event=Change
2. Item=P1_Your_Check_Box
3. Condition=In List
4. Condition Value=others (the return value of your P1_Your_Check_Box when
   others is checked)
5. True Action=Show
6. **Uncheck** Fire On Page Load
7. Affected Elements>Items= P1_text
8. False Action=Hide
9. Affected Elements>Items= P1_text
10. **Check** Fire On Page Load

Comment: For some reason its not working for and item that has multiple check boxes. I have input the item into a table to see what would come out. if i checked multiple boxes it returned  "option1:option2:others"

Comment: What version of apex are you using?

Comment: I've changed the condition and condition value in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If built in dynamic actions in apex wont give you results, you can always patch it up with a jquery or javascript in the main page. 
In the main page under javascript>excute when page loads, try this code

```
$('#P2_NEW_CONTAINER').hide();
$('#P2_NEW_1').click(function(){
    if ($v('P2_NEW_1').indexOf('2') != -1) {
     $('#P2_NEW_CONTAINER').show();
    }
    else{
     $('#P2_NEW_CONTAINER').hide();
    }

});
```

where

- P2_NEW_CONTAINER is the id of the container of your textbox/textfield.it always end with _CONTAINER;
- P2_NEW_1 is the id of your checkbox and;
- "2" is the return value of the "others" check box